# Why Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated?

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

it is my implementation of finding minimum on list:

```
min(L, M) :- min(L, M, M).
min([], M, M).
min([Head|Tail], Acc, M) :- NewAcc is min(Acc, Head), min(Tail, NewAcc, M). 

min([1,2,3,4,5,6], 1).
true.

min([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2).
false.

min([1,2,3,4,5,6], X).
 is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I cant understand why this error happened. Could you explain it to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query, `min([1,2,3,4,5,6], X).` you quickly get to `NewAcc is min(Acc, Head)` where `Acc` has no value (not instantiated). `is/2` requires that *all* variables in the expression be bound so that it can evaluate the expression.

The problem is in your predicate clause:

```
min(L, M) :- min(L, M, M).
```

`M` is a variable in the query, `min([1,2,3,4,5,6], X).` which becomes `Acc` in the first clause of `min/3`. This implementation also doesn't match what you're really needing to do with the extra argument, which is to offer an initial candidate for minimum.

One classic way of doing this is to use the first element of the list as the minimum candidate:

```
min([H|T], Min) :-
    min(T, H, Min).
```

This also means `min([], _)` will fail, which is fine since an empty list doesn't have a minimum.